# How to add arrow from text to node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I am currently using Tikz in order to draw a finite automata. I would need to add an arrow from a bit of text to one of the nodes of the finite automata, as shown in the example.

I have tried created a node with "draw=none". However, this raises two problems. I am unable to write the text desired on two lines and further more, the bounding box for the node is created, although not displayed and thus, the arrow looks really bad, since the bounding box for such a long text is huge.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}

\begin{document}

(not important stuff)

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=2.8cm, semithick]
\node[state] (A)                    {$Alarm$};
\node[state] (B) [above of=A]       {$Reset$};
\node[state] (C) [above right of=A] {$S1$};
\node[state] (D) [right of=A]       {$S2$};
\node[state] (E) [below right of=A] {$S3$};
\node[state] (F) [below of=A]       {$S4$};
\node[state] (G) [left of=A]        {$Open$};
\node[statem, draw=none] (H) [above left of=B] {Reset input(from any state)};

\path (A) edge [loop left]  node {0, 1} (A)
      (B) edge [bend left]  node {1}    (C)
          edge              node {0}    (A)
      (C) edge [bend left]  node {0}    (D)
          edge              node {1}    (A)
      (D) edge [bend left]  node {1}    (E)
          edge              node {0}    (A)
      (E) edge [bend left]  node {1}    (F)
          edge              node {0}    (A)
      (F) edge [bend left]  node {0}    (G)
          edge              node {1}    (A)
      (G) edge [bend left]  node {0}    (B)
          edge [loop left]  node {1}    (G)
      (H) edge              node {}     (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

(more not important stuff)

\end{document}
```

PS Knowing how to move the arrows to the middle of the edge would also be appreciated(at the present time they are at the end of the edge).

[image: example]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` in which you show what you have achieved so far so that it can be a starting point for the users willing to help.

Comment: I have added the example. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the `automata` library and a decoration to place the arrows in the middle of the edges:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,decorations.markings,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
midarr/.style 2 args={
  decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[xshift=3.333pt]{triangle 45} \node[#1] {#2};},
  },
    postaction=decorate,
},
state/.append style={minimum size=35pt},
node distance=1.3cm and 1.3cm
]
\node[state]
  (open) {Open};
\node[state,right=of open]
  (alarm) {Alarm};
\node[state,right=of alarm]
  (s1) {S1};
\node[state,above=of alarm,xshift=10pt]
  (reset) {Reset};
\node[state,below=of alarm,xshift=10pt]
  (s2) {S2};
\node[left=of reset,align=right,yshift=20pt]
  (resetany) {Reset input\\ (from any state)};
\draw[-triangle 45]
  (resetany.east) -- (reset);

\draw[midarr={right=2pt}{1}]
  (s2) -- (alarm);  
\draw[midarr={right=2pt}{0}]
  (reset) -- (alarm);  
\draw[midarr={below=1pt}{0}]
  (s1) -- (alarm);  
\draw[midarr={below left}{0}]
  (s2) to[bend left] (open);  
\draw[midarr={above left}{0}]
  (open) to[bend left] (reset);  
\draw[midarr={above right}{1}]
  (reset) to[bend left] (s1);  
\draw[midarr={below right}{1}]
  (s1) to[bend left] (s2);
\draw[midarr={left}{$0,1$}]
  (alarm) to[out=230,in=130,looseness=2.5] (alarm);
\draw[midarr={left}{1}]
  (open) to[out=230,in=130,looseness=2.5] (open);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There's an `initial` style (refer to the documentation), but I opted for a simple `\node` with some attributes to place the "Reset input (from any state)" text.

And here's a modified version for the code in the question, using the same ideas as before:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,decorations.markings,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
midarr/.style 2 args={
  decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[xshift=3.333pt]{stealth'} \node[#1] {#2};},
  },
    postaction=decorate,
},
state/.append style={minimum size=35pt},
node distance=1.6cm and 1.6cm,
semithick,
>=stealth',
shorten >=1pt
]
\node[state]
  at (0,0)
  (alarm) {Alarm};
\node[state,left=of alarm]
  (open) {Open};
\node[state]
  at (45:2.8cm)
  (s1) {S1};
\node[state,right=of alarm]
  (s2) {S2};
\node[state,above=of alarm]
  (reset) {Reset};
\node[state]
  at (-45:2.8cm)
  (s3) {S3};
\node[state,below=of alarm]
  (s4) {S4};

\draw[midarr={right=2pt}{0}]
  (reset) -- (alarm);  
\draw[midarr={below right=1pt}{1}]
  (s1) -- (alarm);  
\draw[midarr={below=1pt}{0}]
  (s2) -- (alarm);  
\draw[midarr={below left}{0}]
  (s3) -- (alarm);  
\draw[midarr={left=2pt}{1}]
  (s4) -- (alarm);  
\draw[midarr={below left}{0}]
  (s4) to[bend left] (open);  
\draw[midarr={above left}{0}]
  (open) to[bend left] (reset);  
\draw[midarr={above right}{1}]
  (reset) to[out=0,in=132] (s1);  
\draw[midarr={right=2pt}{0}]
  (s1) to[out=-45,in=90] (s2);  
\draw[midarr={right=2pt}{1}]
  (s2) to[out=-90,in=45] (s3);  
\draw[midarr={below right}{1}]
  (s3) to[out=-135,in=0] (s4);  
\draw[midarr={left}{$0,1$}]
  (alarm) to[out=230,in=130,looseness=2.5] (alarm);
\draw[midarr={left}{1}]
  (open) to[out=230,in=130,looseness=2.5] (open);

\node[left=of reset,align=right,yshift=30pt,xshift=10pt]
  (resetany) {Reset input\\ (from any state)};
\draw[-stealth']
  (resetany.east) -- (reset);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @RaduSzasz You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept the answer (if you consider it solved your problem) by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: Accepted it! Cheers!